# Cascading LOV Parent items list too long

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have many parent items in my cascading LOV. Like 14 items.
Apex throws error,  when i input a few of them: `Value too long by 7 characters`.

[image: error massage2]
[image: error massage]

I am using popup LOV and type: SQL query

Is there any way to bypass this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shorten items' names. Perhaps it'll help. For example, instead of P10_ID_PODMIOT, name it P10_IDPM.

Comment: Agree with littlefoot, from the error message it seems that the apex builder input field has a limitation